# ErrorException strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, strtotime

Can anyone help me? this is my controller, when i try to store 'purchase' data it show this message ***strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given***
The error was on the `$purchase->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));` and `$purchaseDetail->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));`

```
public function store(Request $request){
    if($request->category_id == null){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Please Purchase The Product');
    } else{
        // Multipale Data Insert start //
        $purchase = new purchase();
        $purchase->purchase_no = $request->purchase_no;
        $purchase->date        = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));
        $purchase->description = $request->description;
        $purchase->status      = '0';
        $purchase->created_by  = Auth::user()->id;
        DB::transaction(function() use($request,$purchase) {
           if($purchase->save()) {
            // Purchase Details Insert Start //
            $category_id = count($request->category_id);
            for ($i=0; $i < $category_id; $i++) { 
                $purchaseDetail = new purchaseDetail();
                $purchaseDetail->date               = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));
                $purchaseDetail->purchase_id        = $purchase->id;
                $purchaseDetail->supplier_id        = $request->supplier_id[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->category_id        = $request->category_id[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->product_id         = $request->product_id[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->buying_qty         = $request->buying_qty[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->unit_price         = $request->unit_price[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->buying_price       = $request->buying_price[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->discount_amount    = $request->discount_amount[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->ppn                = $request->ppn[$i];
                $purchaseDetail->status              = '0';
                $purchaseDetail->save();
            }
        }
        });
    }
    // Redirect 
    return redirect()->route('purchase.view')->with('success', 'Purchase Added Successfully');
}
```

Hello, i try to change `$purchase->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));` into `$purchase->date = $request->date;`
But the result was ***TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\Project Laravel\alc-pos\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 869***

Comment: Well, looks like `$request->date` is an array. There's nothing much else to say from this code, the error seems pretty explicit.

Comment: As @Jeto said... check the type of $request->date. It's not unusual (e.g. AWS Services) to put any response into an Array. Even if there is only one element. This normalizes the API-behaviour, thus you can always expect array-types,l even if there is just a single element.

Comment: @Jeto how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As for my opnion you must not format your date when saving to database.
Instead you can format it when outputit from database into your blade templates.

Anyway make a check on `$request->date`, seems to be an array.

You can format your date using Laravel accessor in your model like this (example):

```
    public function getFormattedStartDateAttribute()
    {
        return $this->start_date->format('d-m-Y');
    }
```

and then call it in your blade template like this (example):

```
 <input type="text" name="start_date" class="form-control" value="{{$trip->formatted_start_date}}">
```

More info about Laravel Mutators & Accessors : [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Also you can do another thing. On your `schema::create` make:

```
$table->date('date_name_column');
```

and then just save it like follow:

```
        $purchaseDetail->date = $request->input('date');
```

This way the date in your database will be save as follow : YYYY-MM-DD

Hope it helps!

Comment: Updated the answer, try that and tell me if it works for you.