# How to solve: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store the `date` but problems happen.

Input

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control form-control-sm">
       </div> 
    </div>


Controller
public function store(Request $request){
        if($request->category_id == null){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Please Purchase The Product');
        } else{
            // Multipale Data Insert start //
            $purchase = new purchase();
            $purchase->purchase_no = $request->purchase_no;
            $purchase->date        = $request->date; 
            $purchase->description = $request->description;
            $purchase->status      = '0';
            $purchase->created_by  = Auth::user()->id;
            DB::transaction(function() use($request,$purchase) {
               if($purchase->save()) {
                // Purchase Details Insert Start //
                $category_id = count($request->category_id);
                for ($i=0; $i < $category_id; $i++) { 
                    $purchaseDetail = new purchaseDetail();
                    $purchaseDetail->date               = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));
                    $purchaseDetail->purchase_id        = $purchase->id;
                    $purchaseDetail->supplier_id        = $request->supplier_id[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->category_id        = $request->category_id[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->product_id         = $request->product_id[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->buying_qty         = $request->buying_qty[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->unit_price         = $request->unit_price[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->buying_price       = $request->buying_price[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->discount_amount    = $request->discount_amount[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->ppn                = $request->ppn[$i];
                    $purchaseDetail->status              = '0';
                    $purchaseDetail->save();
                }
            }
            });
        }
        // Redirect 
        return redirect()->route('purchase.view')->with('success', 'Purchase Added Successfully');
    }
```

When I store it, an error appears like this:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must
> be of the type array, string given, called in D:\Project
> Laravel\alc-pos\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
> on line 869

I try to change this `$purchase->date = $request->date;`

into this `$purchase->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));` its appears an error like [ErrorException strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496305/errorexception-strtotime-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given):

> strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: and if you try this ? =>$purchase->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $request->date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ));

Comment: What was the output of $request->date when you debugged it?

Comment: @JulienBaldy this happen: Call to a member function format() on array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674623/argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-database-grammarparameterize-must-be-of-the)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `$request->date` is an array. Confirm it by doing `echo print_r($request->date, true);` to confirm that `$request->date` really is an array, and if it is, you can see how it's structured. Take it from there.

There's not really that much to go on here, yet.

Edit:

Final solution (courtesy of @JulienBaldy in the comment section):
Change

`$purchase->date        = $request->date;`

into

`$purchase->date        = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $request->date[0]));`

Comment: Yes it is an array, output: `Array ( [0] => 2020-10-26 )`

Comment: so try this : $purchase->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $request->date[0]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ));

Comment: @Adrian nah, still the same problem.. im sorry if asking to much im newbie on this :')

Comment: @JulienBaldy this happen: Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: @Naldaff oh yes sorry. without format ! $purchase->date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $request->date[0]));